# Postgresql XA Transaction Exception

Tags: java, postgresql, wildfly, distributed-transactions

I am working with wildfly XADataSources(two). One pointing to a readwrite PostgreSQL DB (A) and the other one to a readonly DB (B). The next error is shown when a I'm trying to read from B and write on A:

**Suppressed: org.postgresql.xa.PGXAException: Error preparing transaction**

I already set the **max_prepared_transactions** to a non-zero value as the documentation suggests.

Any suggestion?

Complete stack trace:

```
or call us at:  (101) 848-5866  x and include Incident #: techcr-lpd1281-300653: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1208)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
        at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:89)
        at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.commit(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:178)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:433)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.CallableMethodHandler.invoke(CallableMethodHandler.java:42)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
        at org.jboss.weldx.transaction.UserTransaction$112420245$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.commit(Unknown Source)
        at com.snap.common.utils.TransactionUtil.commit(TransactionUtil.java:71)
        at com.snap.web.bean.application.SearchApplicationTransactionTests.smart_aroundBody4(SearchApplicationTransactionTests.java:339)
        at com.snap.web.bean.application.SearchApplicationTransactionTests$AjcClosure5.run(SearchApplicationTransactionTests.java:1)
        at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
        at com.snap.common.log.MethodLogger.around(MethodLogger.java:62)
        at com.snap.web.bean.application.SearchApplicationTransactionTests.smart(SearchApplicationTransactionTests.java:287)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:162)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:201)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Suppressed: org.postgresql.xa.PGXAException: Error preparing transaction
                at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.prepare(PGXAConnection.java:323)
                at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.prepare(XAManagedConnection.java:330)
                at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelPrepare(XAResourceRecord.java:218)
                at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doPrepare(BasicAction.java:2662)
                at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doPrepare(BasicAction.java:2612)
                at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.prepare(BasicAction.java:2155)
                at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.End(BasicAction.java:1501)
                at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:96)
                at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
                at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1200)
                ... 97 more
        Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute PREPARE TRANSACTION during recovery
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412)
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2125)
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:297)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:264)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:244)
                at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.prepare(PGXAConnection.java:315)
                ... 106 more
        Suppressed: org.postgresql.xa.PGXAException: Error rolling back prepared transaction
                at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.rollback(PGXAConnection.java:415)
                at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.rollback(XAManagedConnection.java:346)
                at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelAbort(XAResourceRecord.java:369)
                at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doAbort(BasicAction.java:3017)
                at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doAbort(BasicAction.java:2996)
                at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.phase2Abort(BasicAction.java:1979)
                at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.End(BasicAction.java:1517)
                at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:96)
                at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
                at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1200)
                ... 97 more
        Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute ROLLBACK PREPARED during recovery
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412)
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2125)
                at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:297)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:264)
                at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:244)
                at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.rollback(PGXAConnection.java:405)
                ... 106 more
```

Answer (score 0):

...readonly DB (B). ... error ... trying to ... write on B. ... Any suggestion?

umm, don't try to write a read-only database?

Am I right in thinking you are running against an HA slave? "cannot execute PREPARE TRANSACTION during recovery" is usually a symptom of trying to send mutations to a replica instead of the master. The message is a little confusing, because the slaves are basically in a state of continuously 'recovering' the transaction log from the master to keep themselves up to date, effectively rendering them read-only.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake, I'm reading from B and trying to write on A. You're right. B is a replica.

Comment: pgsql seems to not optimize that case properly. It should return 'XA_RDONLY' from the prepare to the read-only replica, since it doesn't have to perform any mutation on that side and thus doesn't care that it is unable to, but it doesn't distinguish that case from the more general one. Enlist the read-only one as a non-xa datasource instead maybe?

Comment: Thanks @jbosstxnerd, I appreciate your suggestion.